# Load a stand-alone jar in memory to query from a Python program

Tags: java, python, jar

I have [this](https://github.com/dair-iitd/OpenIE-standalone#running-from-a-stand-alone-jar) stand-alone jar which I can use via the command line. I basically want to load this jar once and have a loop which will send in the queries (without loading the jar again and again).
I have a python script which takes in input from MongoDB, and I want that script to send that as input to this Jar (without loading it again as loading the jar takes ~1 minute and I have 55M input lines).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem correctly ,  i see it you are doing it wrong .
if you use a java tool and a java library , use it with java . 
write java code that takes the input from mongodb , and write java code that will depend on this OpenIE lib to execute its functionality .
this way the classes will be loaded once into jvm and will be available fora furture use...

if you insist on using python , as i see it you cant do anything . 
every time you run the jar , you re crate the JVM . and every time the code of the lib ends his run , the jvm is thrown.

if you still insist on using python to wrap around this library with different inputs , i would recommend to consider multi-threaded approach , so each thread runs its own instance of the library .